# Writing to a text file and losing data in Python?

Tags: database, ironpython

I am logging data using IronPython (sensor OEM requires this), and writing that collected data to a `.txt` file using the first snippet below.  My goal is to make real-time calculations on the collected data (like a running window variance), and plot it in real-time.  I am reading the `.txt` file into a script I've written in Spyder.

I am losing about 3/4 of the data points somewhere between the data collection in my first script, and the data read in my Spyder script for the math calculation and visualization.

I am looking for some feedback for the way I am writing my data, and reading it; and if I am risking losing data somewhere along this way.

```
file = open("C:\\Users\Documents\\test4.txt", "a")
writer = csv.writer(file)
while True:
    writer.writerow(myFunction())    
    file.flush()
```

In Spyder, I am reading in this file like the following:

```
def animate(i):

    data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\Documents\\test4.txt")
    data.columns = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
```

Comment: Is all the data in `test4.txt`? If so your first bit of code is irrelevant. See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: You're probably losing data because you never close the file.

Comment: @PeterWood Should I add `file.close()` after the flush?